# Post method in Rest always returning '405 Method Not Allowed' but working fine in my dev machine

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am using jetty with spring boot, and implemented few rest calls, all the get methods are working fine in both the environment `dev` and `qa` , but post is always returning '405 Method Not Allowed', I checked everything like headers, body and other parameters everything seems correct.

I am using spring rest implementation, any ideas why its failing.

method Definition:

```
 @RequestMapping(value ="/resub" ,method=RequestMethod.POST )
 public ResponseEntity<?> resub(@RequestBody Subscription Subscription,HttpServletRequest request ){
    try {
           // call to other service methods
        //}
        } catch (Exception e) {
          if(e instanceof HttpClientErrorException)
              return commonUtil.getExceptionResponse(e.getMessage());
          else 
              return commonUtil.getExceptionResponse("Unknown Error Occured");  }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer should really be a comment, but unfortunately I don't have 50 rep yet.

The first problem I notice is that you're closing the resub() function before it even gets to the catch statement.

That doesn't explain why you would get a 405 http status response though.

"The principal cause of this issue is either using the wrong method (not applicable to your case) or multiple handlers have been defined for the same verb/method, and one of the handlers is blocking the expected handler from processing the request. ... IIS processes handlers from first to last based on the order handler entries in the applicationHost.config and web.config files, where the first matching combination of path, verb, resource, etc., will be used to handle the request [1]."

Hope this helps, if not let me know and I can continue trying to help :)

[1] - https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/troubleshooting-http-405-errors-after-publishing-web-api-applications

Comment: so, now you have the rep ... :)

Comment: Thanks, I'm still 1 short though hahaha :)

Comment: @MrPigeon, method definition is correct it seems you didn't notice the start curly brace which is there on the same line of function name .

Comment: @MrPigeon, Method is also correct and I have unique handler defined and i too thought that its because of multiple handlers might be its contradicting with any other service in QA, will check that..and let you know.. :)

Comment: @Ali786, Sorry for the delay, got caught up with an issue at work. I did see the first curly brace on the same line as the function name, but then you open and close the try block and follow with another curly brace which would close the function. I copied the code verbatim into IntelliJ and got the error that a catch or finally was expected and unexpected token after the second curly brace after the try block.

Let me know how you go with searching for multiple handlers. Until then, I'm afraid I don't have any other ideas.